# estoy trabajando con la versión de Laravel Framework 5.8.38 pero tengo el error -----> errno: 150 "Foreign key c onstraint is incorrectly formed ??"

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, php5, laravel-6

primero  ejecuto la migración para la creación de la **tabla users** y se crea sin problema.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego creo la **tabla professions**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y luego quiero añadir un **nuevo campo llamado profession_id** a la **table users** atravez de otro migracion con este **codigo**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

al ejecutar el **php artisan migrate:refresh** en el **bash** me aparece este **error** y puedo crear la llave foranea(primaria) o el foreign entre tabla users y profession
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Creo que el problema lo tienes porque cuando has creado el campo id de professions has especificado que sea bigIncrements, que está bien. Pero luego al querer hacer la relación has puesto el campo profession_id con bigInteger. El problema es que el campo bigIncrements es UNSIGNED osea, sin signo, solo números positivos. Mientras que el campo bigInteger es SIGNED, puede tener números negativos. El campo correcto sería unsignedBigInteger. [En la documentación](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/migrations#creating-columns) se especifican todos esos detalles.